# GraalVm Error: libgfortran.so.3 for running R code in Node (Ubuntu)

Tags: java, r, node.js, ubuntu, graalvm

I am running a Node application using GraalVM. My Node code contains both R and Java interop code.

I installed R using GraalVM Updater:

`gu install r`

Node program:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

const BigInteger = Java.type('java.math.BigInteger')


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  var text = 'Hello World from Graal.js!<br> '

  // Using Java standard library classes
  text += BigInteger.valueOf(10).pow(100)
          .add(BigInteger.valueOf(43)).toString() + '<br>'

  // Using R methods to return arrays
  text += Polyglot.eval('R',
      'ifelse(1 > 2, "no", paste(1:42, c="|"))') + '<br>'

  // Using R interoperability to create graphs
  text += Polyglot.eval('R',
    `svg();
     require(lattice);
     x <- 1:100
     y <- sin(x/10)
     z <- cos(x^1.3/(runif(1)*5+10))
     print(cloud(x~y*z, main="cloud plot"))
     grDevices:::svg.off()
    `);

  res.send(text)
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

Console output:

```
Example app listening on port 3000!
FastR unexpected failure: error loading libR from: /.sdkman/candidates/java/20.1.0.r11-grl/languages/R/lib/libR.so.
Message: libgfortran.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Troubleshooting: 

  * Please run /home/.sdkman/candidates/java/20.1.0.r11-grl/languages/R/bin/configure_fastr. It will check that your system has the necessary dependencies and if not it will suggest how to install them.

  * If this does not help, please open an issue on https://github.com/oracle/fastr/ or reach us on https://graalvm.slack.com.


/home/server.js:19
  text += Polyglot.eval('R',

... other logs
```

I have also installed  build-essential, gfortran, libxml2 and libc++-dev as suggested by GraalVm compiler.

Is it an issue with GraaLVM or Ubuntu FastR package installation does by GraalVM?

Comment: What version of graalvm is this being run on?

Answer (score 1):

Please try again with the latest version of GraalVM. 20.1.0 is already several months old; if you try again with 20.3.0 you should get lots of bugfixed that where included in the newer version.

Also, note that the error message even tells you to run a specific command on your shell, `/home/.sdkman/candidates/java/20.1.0.r11-grl/languages/R/bin/configure_fastr`. Did you do that? Did that help? What was the output of that, was there an error?

Thanks,
Christian